# How to fix the Runtime Error In server using jqueryMobile in MVC3?

Tags: jquery-mobile, telerik-mvc

I had develop a small jquery-mobile application in telerik MVC3. It is working in local machine  and i uplod into my server and tested it works for desktop devices but when I test in Mobile (Iphone) it shows Error Like runtime Error

```
<!--web.config Cofiguration File-->
<configuration>
  <system.Web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.Web>
</configuration>
```

I can't understand why it showing only in mobile device please help me. How can I solve this error.

Comment: `<customErrors mode="OfF"/>`, maybe is a typo in Off

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response i have change <customErrors mode="Off"/> but it showing same error..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't see the error page due to the fact that JQueryMobile only shows a small popup with the message "Error loading page".

You can disable Ajax and this way see all html pages as a regular web app would.
Just add this script between Jquery and Jquery mobile script references

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        }); 
</script>
```